# Why Whatsapp data consumption is low

Tags: whatsapp

Whatsapp has been around for a considerable amount of time. People send videos, audios and images using it. Apparently, I noticed something weird about all these. I was sent a video whose size was 24MB. Before downloading this, I cleared my data consumption for Whatsapp, then proceeded o download the video. When I checked data consumption for Whatsapp after the download was completed, I found it to be 14MB.

So I thought the consumption measurement by the device was mad. I purchased 15MB data bundle from my service provided and requested the video be sent again. Once more, the download was 14MB because I was left with about 866KB wlof data bundle. I tried with other files apart from videos and it still worked without any apparent reduction in quality.

Can anyone explain this phenomenon? Is it the kind of data compression used, and of so, which? Is there anything they're doing different from conventional data connections?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The compression is done on the server side, as mentioned in the below link, you'd need to reverse engineer and find it yourself (seems it has been changed and optimized) https://www.quora.com/What-video-compression-library-is-used-by-WhatsApp

Comment: The discussion in Quora seems to be that of people amazed by whatever algorithm Whatsapp is using. No mention of what they used. I'm wondering if decompressing the Whatsapp apk is of any use.